# How to hold jquery template files as external template files with multiple templates in each file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-templates

I am trying to hold a file full of templates that can be loaded up into a page upon page load. Is this really possible? Let me show you what I mean:

**Usually**, we do this:

```
<script id = "template1" type= "text/x-jquery-tmpl">BLAH</script>
<script id = "template2" type= "text/x-jquery-tmpl">BLAH</script>
<script id = "template3" type= "text/x-jquery-tmpl">BLAH</script>
```

**Instead** how can we do something like this

```
<script id = "all_templates" type= "text/x-jquery-tmpl">TEMPLATE1, TEMPLATE2, TEMPLATE3</script>
```

Comment: You'd be better off translating the templates into JavaScript at the server, and then loading a wad of JavaScript (minimized).

Comment: True, that's even better.

Comment: @Pointy: What do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you can simply use an AJAX request to load a page containing the separate `<script>` templates and then use the normal jQuery DOM functions to access them:

```
var templates = {};
$.ajax({
    url: 'templates.html',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('script', data).each(function() {
            templates[this.id] = $(this).text();
        });
    }
});
```

However, an even cleaner solution would be transforming your templates into a single JSON object on the server side and load that one.

Comment: I am just trying to pass in JSON (made by server) to html so that the client can manage that. Just trying to keep the html away from the server guys - the ones I work with prefer that as well. This is a great solution! Thanks.

Comment: @TheifMaster: Can you also add the best way templates.html should look like.

Comment: Could be a simple document containing just the script tags.

Comment: @bluejamesbond: Fyi, that edit you suggested was invalid. The context is the *second* parameter. However, `data.find('script')` could do the job, too.